# Only single image is loading in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, imageview

In one page of my viewpager there is 3 images the images are coming from backend. But only first image is loading remaining images are not loading.I debug the image names inside onstart the image names are coming inside Android Monitor.

[image: Now my screen look like this]

my imagefragment xml look like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgfragment_imageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:background="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And Corresponding java file look like below

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.io.File;
import in.creace.magdreams.MagdreamsApplication;
import in.creace.magdreams.R;

public class ImageFragment extends Fragment{
   private View mView;
   private ImageView image;
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_imagefragment, null);
    return mView;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    String path=getArguments().getString("IMAGEPATH");
    image=(ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.imgfragment_imageview);
    File file = new File(path);
    MagdreamsApplication.getInstance().getAquery().id(image).image(file,400);
    super.onStart();
  }
}
```

Please go through my code. Did i make any mistake in this code? If the code have any mistake please correct it

Comment: What is MagdreamsApplication and what is it doing?

Comment: It's a public class for just providing instance for aquery...I also used glide instead of that but same issue occured

Comment: This API is not quite understandable. But what I can see - you are loading only one image. So how the others could be fetched?

Comment: The image is like hotspots each time the imageview is coming the class is called with corresponding path.. The above image have 3 image hotspots so from parent class we call this class 3 times. Each time the url of image are also passed... The url of all the three images are coming...i loged that

Comment: Attach all code, with the corresponding viewpager stuff.

Answer (score 0):

That may have occurred because of heap size or memory issue. You can solve it using :

1 - Any image library such as picasso or glide(mostly used)

2- Download the image and compress it using Base64 and the display the images

Best of Luck!